# laravel controller синтаксис ,

Tags: php, laravel, mvc, controller

как правильно написать что при каждом цикле получить последовательную цифру типа

```
$store->img_1 
$store->img_2 
$store->img_3
```

---

```
 $store = new Store();

 foreach($files as $key => $file){

                $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName(); 
                $img = $filename = md5($file->getClientOriginalName() . time()) . "." . $file->getClientOriginalExtension(); 
                $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension(); 
                $check=in_array($extension,$allowedfileExtension); 

                if($check){ 
                    $key++;

                    $file->move('img', $img);
                    $store->img_.$key = $img;

                    echo "Upload Successfully";
                }


            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте следующее:

```
$imageField = 'img_' . $key;

$store->$imageField;
```

А какова конечная цель ?

Вы могли бы полученный массив с файлами сериализовать в **json** и хранить значение в одном столбце, например, **images**. В момент , когда Вам нужно будет получить содержимое , достаточно попросту перевести json - строку в обычный ассоциативный массив , для этого используется функция **json_decode** с доп. параметром **assoc** в значении **true**.

Для удобства это можно реализовать с помощью мутаторов ( [Eloquent: Mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators)
) :

```
public function setImagesAttribute($images)
{
    if ($images) {
        $this->attributes['images'] = json_encode($images);
    }
}

public function getImagesAttribute()
{
    return json_decode($this->attributes['images'], true);
}
```